# API for Android to Receive Weather Alert Triggers?

Tags: android, alert, weather, weather-api

I am developing an Android weather application for a class project with a team, and one of the features we'd like to include is to get emergency weather alerts/warnings. Some of the resources I've considered are:

- **Wireless Emergency Alert (WEA):** I can't find any resources on trigger events or listeners when an Android device receives an Emergency Alert with FEMA. I could understand if developers shouldn't have access to display information when an emergency alert is in progress.
- **openweathermap.com:** This is the primary API we are planning to use, its API responses are simple and meet our needs. They also provide triggers that will send a response when a condition is met without having to constantly make a request for if the condition is met. However none of the conditions they support include emergency events such as a tornado/hurricane/flood/winter storm.
- **Yahoo Weather:** I've been looking into this, but it seems like the Yahoo API is moved to another website that hits a dead end. Not planning to set up a developer account if I'm not sure it's going to work. Additionally, their API provides tornadoes and similar as a condition, but this must be requested rather than triggered from their API.
- **weather.gov:** I've been combing through their documentation, but I can't find if they provide trigger events or even tornado events.

Is there an API that sends trigger events for emergency weather conditions (as mentioned above)? Or would I be better off making requests periodically from the application?

Thanks

Comment: It's not ideal but you can use accuweather (you need to use pulling once a day or several hours) but I will check it just in case https://developer.accuweather.com/accuweather-alerts-api/apis/get/alerts/v1/%7BlocationKey%7D

Comment: The OpenFEMA web API now serves IPAWS data (WEA). They have introduced a 24 hour delay so these messages are not confused with the real-time alerts. Still might be useful for some events though. https://www.fema.gov/openfema-data-page/ipaws-archived-alerts--v1